# Given independent random variables $X \sim U(0,1)$, find $P(X_1<X_2<X_3)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given $X_1, X_2,X_3$ are independent random variables from $U(0,1)$, find $P(X_1<X_2<X_3)$.

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve the issue. If problems occur on the road, please describe them, so that a potential answer can go straightforward to the essence. This way, the question becomes relevant for the community. Note that not providing any content usually attracts many downvotes. (This causes frustration for both sides. There is even more frustration when somebody provides a quick answer, as it would be the case in this case for "symmetry reasons"...)

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, each ordering of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is equally likely, so the probability is $1/3!=1/6$.